# Unable to load type "FluentValidation.Attributes.ValidatorAttribute"

Tags: c#, .net-core, fluentvalidation

System.TypeLoadException: 'Could not load type 'FluentValidation.Attributes.ValidatorAttribute' from assembly 'FluentValidation, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7de548da2fbae0f0'.'

I am getting the above error after upgrade from .netcore2 to .netcore6.I tried upgrading to the latest 10.x but in vain. Also, there is no Nuget for verson 9.0.0 as thrown in the error, only 9.0.1 is availble and that also throws the same error.

Comment: downgrade package 
my issue I installed latest version and when I downgrade to previous major version it is working fine

Answer (score 3):

Starting from FluentValidation version 8.0 that `ValidatorAttribute` has been moved to a separate NuGet package [`FluentValidation.ValidatorAttribute`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FluentValidation.ValidatorAttribute/).

From the [documentation](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/upgrading-to-8.html#validatorattribute-and-attributedvalidatorfactory-have-been-moved-to-a-separate-package)

> Use of the ValidatorAttribute to wire up validators is no longer recommended and have been moved to a separate `FluentValidation.ValidatorAttribute` package.

Note that using that attribute is not recommended anymore,
and is even considered legacy.
For that reason that NuGet package has the below notice.

> This package has been deprecated as it is legacy and is no longer maintained.

The documentation shows how to migrate

> - In ASP.NET Core projects, you should use the service provider to wire models to their validators (this has been the default behaviour for ASP.NET Core projects since FluentValidation 7)
> - For desktop or mobile applications, we recommend using an IoC container to wire up validators, although you can still use the attribute approach by explicitly installing the `FluentValidation.ValidatorAttribute` package.
> - In legacy ASP.NET projects (MVC 5 and WebApi 2), the `ValidatorAttribute` is still the default approach, and the `FluentValidation.ValidatorAttribute` package will be automatically installed for compatibility. However, we recommend using an IoC container instead if you can.

Comment: version 11 not working version 10 working fine